# Writing binary content directly to the client bypassing the Grails view layer

Tags: grails

The following action is meant to write the binary content of `bytes` directly to the client completely bypassing the Grails view layer:

```
def actionName = {
  byte[] bytes = ...
  ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()
  out.write(bytes)
  out.flush()
  out.close()
  return false
}
```

I was under the impression that `return false` would make Grails completely skip the view layer. However, that appears not to be the case since the above code still makes Grails search for `/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/controllerName/actionName.jsp` (which fails with a 404, since no such file exists).

Question:

- **Given the code above, how do I completely bypass the view layer in Grails?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as Grails tries to render the view if `response.contentType.startsWith('text/html')`. This seems to be a known bug, see [GRAILS-1223](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1223).

Here are two work arounds:

1. Use `render(contentType: "text/html", text: htmlString)` as suggested in [GRAILS-1223](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1223). This will bypass the view layer.
2. Clear the content type with `response.contentType = ''`. This will also bypass the view layer. However, note that the content will be served to the end-user without Content-Type which can confuse some browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You should return null or nothing at all, which is interpreted as null. Here's some working code from an action that sends a dynamically generated PDF:

```
def pdf = {
   byte[] content = ...
   String filename = ...
   response.contentType = 'application/octet-stream'
   response.setHeader 'Content-disposition', "attachment; filename=\"$filename\""
   response.outputStream << content
   response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

Comment: Hi Burt! Thanks for the answer and nice code. However, the code does not solve the "completely bypass the view layer". Please see my answer below. Do you know why response.contentType == null is needed for it to work? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith is it alway response.outputStream.flush() or do I have to add  response.outputStream.close() as well? and what is with return null at the end?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith do you have an idea on this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658021/image-byte-to-response-outputstream-in-grails-leads-to-cannot-forward-after