# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed" in Grails

Tags: java, spring, servlets, grails, grails-2.0

I have a Grails 2.2.4 application running. The application does some image uploading tasks and shows the uploaded images in a list. Everything works fine, but sometime I get the error below. I googled after that but I could not find a proper answer. I cannot find the how the error belongs to my code.

Sometime when I load my page an the error occurs I only see a white page with a 2000 and a 0 written on the top left of the page. There is no error in the console.

[image]

**What produces this error and how can I prevent it?**

```
Sep 11, 2013 8:29:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:314)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:279)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: You're trying to forward a request after the response has already been committed, either knowingly or because of the framework itself. Post the related code.

Comment: The problem is I do not know what the related code is. What could cause this problem so I can post the code?

Comment: Is this a [Déjà vu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18658021/2051952) or  are you still stuck with the same old issue?

Comment: @dmahapatro I still stuck with this issue.

Comment: I suppose you have also tried closing the outstream?

Comment: @dmahapatro yes what I do to send the images to the browser is like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658021/image-byte-to-response-outputstream-in-grails-leads-to-cannot-forward-after

Comment: @dmahapatro do you have any idea?

Comment: Looks like codelark and others had given that idea is the older question.

Comment: @dmahapatro I mean do you have an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Provide a sample project showcasing the defect, in github, if viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error caused by the [Browser detection plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/browser-detection).

When you use the plugin in controller methods there is no problem with the session.

I had problems with my session when I use the GSP tags of this plugin like:

```
<browser:isMobile>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Put the below condition before render or redirect statement in Grails controller and see if it can resolve the issue.

```
if(!response.isCommited())
{
 // render or redirect
}
```

Check if the control goes to inside the condition and based on that debug it.

Comment: What should I do if the response is commited?

Comment: Should I do that also for forward?

Comment: @confile: Try it wherever you are forwarding/render/redirect and debug it to check if response is already commited.

Comment: Can you check my code here if there is any error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658021/image-byte-to-response-outputstream-in-grails-leads-to-cannot-forward-after

Comment: I did add comment to your question about exception when rendering in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658021/image-byte-to-response-outputstream-in-grails-leads-to-cannot-forward-after/18854093#18854093

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `generate` scope in your code([your stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658021/image-byte-to-response-outputstream-in-grails-leads-to-cannot-forward-after/18854093#18854093)) to this

```
 generate {
                def outputStream = response.outputStream
                try {
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;")
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${imageName}${imageExtension}\"")
                outputStream << imageByteArray
                outputStream.flush()
                } catch (Exception exception){
                    log.debug('getImage() - Canceled download?', exception)
                    try {
                        outputStream.close()
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        log.debug('Exception on close', exception)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you have changed?

Comment: I changed...
>1)`IOException` to `Exception`(I guess you have other exception).
>2)`response.setContentType("image/jpeg")` to `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;")`
>3)included last statement(response.setHeader(...)) in try block.

Comment: Why do you use octet-stream if I only transfer jpeg images?

Comment: If you transfer only `jpeg` you can ignore my second change(but it would work also).
Did you get exception again?

Comment: yes, many people say that outputStream.close() and outputStream.flush() is not needed. Why do you use it?

Comment: When you write data to a stream, some buffering happens. You can't be sure when the entire data you have written will actually be sent. We do call the close() on the file/buffered writers at the end.

So in order to be sure that before we call the close(), all the data you have written actually gets out to the file, we call the flush() just before the close().

Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29